# Chrome Extension Messaging - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, svelte

Consider the following code:

Somewhere in my Svelte Template code as part of an await function and error is caught:

```
{:catch error}
        <b>There was an Error</b>
        <p>{error.message}</p>
        {throwError()}
{/await}
```

In my Svelte script tag I have a function that deals with that error, it sends a message to the chrome extensions background script:

```
function throwError() {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(exID, {
            message: 'removeIframe'
        })
    }
```

The below is then triggered in the background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener (
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request != null || request != undefined) {
            dataFromApp = request;  
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                     message: 'removeiFrame',
                     action: dataFromApp,
                }, 
                function(response) {
                });  
            }); 
        }
    }
);
```

Then in my content script I have something to capture that message like:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
    ///do stuff
}
```

My problem is that this all seems to happen too quickly and the `addEventListener` is not present at the time the message is sent, so I get this warning in my `background.js` console:

```
Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://bkklcdioeabcfmcgkdfaodnmpiopkgnn/background.js:65:35
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to make sure the `addEventListener` in the content script is present and ready to receive messages from a script that is fired when svelte builds the ui ?

Comment: 1) onMessageExternal is only for messages sent by the web page scripts, it also requires externally_connectable in manifest.json. Your content script or your iframe scripts should use the standard messaging and onMessage. 2) There's no addEventListener so I guess you mean addListener, in which case it'd be a problem only if you register it not in the same *event loop task* as sending. 3) The tab that sent the message isn't necessarily the active one so instead of chrome.tabs.query you should use `sender.tab.id`, or even better use sendResponse directly, see the documentation for more info.

Comment: hiya.. yes.. the onMessageExternal is used to pick up a script / message from a web app that is on another server which sends the background script a message. Its the only way that I can communicate with my extension via an external website. I'll look into sender.tab.id and sendResponse.. thanks!

Comment: hyy how to send message from extension to external website.